# Switching ownership between two smart pointers that point to same resource (new type necessary?)

Tags: c++, task, smart-pointers

I need a smart pointer that deletes the underlying resource whenever it runs out of scope (like `unique_ptr`), yet can be duplicated manifold. It should be constructible from `std::weak_ptr` to elevate temporary ownership and in case of it running out of scope it will delete the resource in any case and invalidate the other ptrs (e.g. through a control block).

Let me explain with a non-compiling example: In the following code I try to establish ownership over a os-specific thread implementation via a custom smart pointer: `twin_ptr` This pointer will own a resource only if no other `twin_ptr` owns the same resource. Copying a twin pointer will leave the original ptr "owning" while the copied twin pointer will be something like `std::weak_ptr`, it will just reference the object but can leave scope without deleting it. In this way I can now establish threads that either 1) own themselves or 2) are owned by another thread and switch between these two forms at any stage.

**NOTE**: I don't have an implementation of `twin_ptr`! The concept is just to have a smart pointer that passes ownership to his *brother* in case ownership is `released()`.

Here's what I mean:

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>

using allocator_t = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;

template <typename T>
class twin_ptr;

struct task
{
    task() = default;

    task(int config, std::packaged_task<void()> fn, twin_ptr<task>* handle)
        :   fn_{ std::move(fn)}
    {
        // Will invoke "worker" in another thread
        // "handle" param will be passed to thread func as void* const
        task_creation_foo_specific_to_my_os(&worker, handle);
    }

    static auto worker(void* const arg) -> void {
        {
            // Copies the twin_ptr into to task scope, copied instance will not be owning by default
            twin_ptr<task> handle = *static_cast<twin_ptr<task>*>(arg);
            handle->fn_();
        }
        // End of scope will delete the task object in case our twin_ptr is still
        // owning it.
    }

    std::packaged_task<void()> fn_;
};

auto create_task(int config, std::packaged_task<void()> fn, allocator_t allocator = {})
{
    auto ptr = twin_ptr<task>{};
    
    ptr = allocate_twin<task>(allocator, config, std::move(fn), &ptr);

    return ptr;
}


int main()
{
    twin_ptr<task> ptr = create_task();

    // Will release ownership and carry it to the thread-internal copy of the twin_ptr
    // (thus lifetime management will be done by the task from now on)
    ptr.release(); 

    printf("-- end--\n");
}
```

I can't compile the code because `twin_ptr` implementation is missing, but I hope it's clear, otherwise please ask

**Note**: Synchronisation primitives are missing deliberately to make it concise. The copying of the `twin_ptr` in the thread obviously should be done AFTER the assignement operator in `create_task()` has completed.

### Question:

Is it already possible to write this functional part with default standard library functions or is do you see a way how I achieve the same functonality in another elegant way?

Comment: its never obvious, otherwise you would not need to ask. Please incldue the compiler error message in the question

Comment: Why cant you just use std::shared_ptr for this? Let create_task create a shared pointer,  and pass it to worker using a lambda that captures that shared pointer by value. It is how I pass objects between threads. The packaged task can then run the lambda.

Comment: More precisely my task will then have the lambda as a copy, and the constructor of the task accepts a lambda (invokable). packaged_task is internal helper then not visible on the task itself.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It's not about the errors, it's about the overarching concept. This is why i didn't include it.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Because if both the task and the user use a shared_ptr, the task won't be deleted if the user shared_ptr goes out of scope which is what I want. The user should always be in control of the deletion of the task object IF he decides to have an owning pointer. Otherwise he can release the shared_ptr and the detached thread will delete itself.

Comment: This really needs an [mcve] that includes the definition of `twin_ptr`.

Comment: What happens to the non-owning `twin_ptr`s after the owner destroys the held object? Can you move from a `twin_ptr`?

Comment: @Caleth The same that happens to std::weak_ptr, it will release nothing and the user can possibly check it with expired(). You can move a twin ptr.

Comment: how? Especially in the case of a moved owner?

Comment: @glades So you want the task to be cancelled/not run when the client of that task goes out of scope? What I think you are trying to do : You want to pass a function to an executor (thread) that will execute the function in the future. But when the client that scheduled that function goes out of scope then that function should no longer be called. Is that what you are trying to do? I think the WHAT here is quite important, since you seem to be focused on a HOW now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it already possible to write this functional part with default standard library functions.

Yes. You have one `std::shared_ptr`, and hand out `std::weak_ptr`s that point to the same object.

```
class task : public std::enable_shared_from_this<task>
{
    task() = default;

    task(int config, std::packaged_task<void()> fn)
        :   fn_{ std::move(fn)}
    {
    }

    void start()
    {
        // Will invoke "worker" in another thread
        // synchronisation needed to ensure handle is assigned in worker before constructor returns
        task_creation_foo_specific_to_my_os(&worker, this);
    }

    static auto worker(void* const arg) -> void {
        auto handle = *static_cast<task*>(arg)->weak_from_this();
        // ...
        if (auto ptr = handle->lock()) ptr->fn_();
        // ...
    }

    std::packaged_task<void()> fn_;

public:
    static std::shared_ptr<task> create_task(int config, std::packaged_task<void()> fn, allocator_t allocator = {})
    {
        auto ptr = std::allocate_shared<task>(allocator, config, fn);
        ptr->start();
        return ptr;
    }
};
```

If you want to be extra careful, you can have an uncopyable object with a `std::shared_ptr` member, rather than taking care to never copy the `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: There is a flaw in your example: `class task : std::enable_shared_from_this<task>`. `std::enable_shared_from_this` _must_ be inherited `public` to work properly. (I just painfully learnt this lesson in my daily business these days...)

Comment: Amazing! I didn't know about enable_shared_from_this,. thanks for bringing that to my attention! Will the temporary std:.shared_ptr weak_from_this decrease the reference count in the handed out shared_ptr?

Comment: @glades within the scope of the `if`, there is a second `shared_ptr`, which will defer the destruction of the task while `fn_` is running. Not destroying the `packaged_task` while it runs is a good thing.

Comment: @Caleth I can see that. The destruction of the package_task will only take place once the task object is destructed, and for that it  doesn't matter as the destructor will stop the task execution anyway before the actual invalidation of the class memory (not shown here).

Comment: Another question: By the time the ctor finishes, the construction of std::shared_ptr will not have fully completed, so a call to weak_from_this() will refer to a control block that might not be fully initialized? Isn't this potentially UB?

Comment: @glades oops, yes

Comment: @Caleth Any idea how to eloquently manouver around this problem?

Comment: @Caleth Cool thanks! One last problem: In this case it could happen that a caller to create_task might release() the shared_ptr immediately after the call, in which case weak_ptr::lock() would return an empty shared_ptr and never execute the function, even though it could as well run detached on the next try when the task function gets CPU time before create_task exits. This is really arbitrary behaviour, but I think I can easily fix it with a synchronisation primitive in the start() function.